# How to monitor WCF Service up time using Performance Counters?

Tags: windows, wcf, performancecounter, perfmon

I'd like to know what is the up-time of WCF service using Performance Counters. 
Is there a specific counter for that? Or is there a way to get this information from other counters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no WCF performance counter that will give you the uptime.

However,

- if you host it **in IIS**, you can use the *'Service Uptime'* in *'Web Service'*, or
- if you host it differently (e.g. **Windows Service, Console Application**), you can use the *'Elapsed Time'* in *'Process'* (unless you don't start/stop the WCF host when the process starts/stops).

Comment: Thanks, Josef. But the service is hosted in Windows Service.

Comment: I see. I added the non-IIS-hosted case to my answer.